# Invalid packaging for parent pom org.code.exec-maven.plugin:1.4 must be pom but is "maven-plugin"

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, artifactory, mvn-repo

I getting below error while I compile maven project with mvn, even `exec-maven.plugin-1.4.pom` file is available on the artifactory:

```
Downloading : https://domain.abc/public/org/code/exec-maven.plugin/1.4/exec-maven.plugin-1.4.pom
[ERROR]Invalid packaging for parent pom org.code.exec-maven.plugin:1.4  must be pom but is "maven-plugin @"
[ERROR]Invalid packaging for parent pom org.code.exec-maven.plugin:1.4  must be pom but is "maven-plugin @"
[FATAL] The parent from cycle  :om org.code.exec-maven.plugin:1.4 -> om org.code.exec-maven.plugin:1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `org.code.exec-maven.plugin:1.4` as parent POM, but this is a Maven plugin, not a parent POM.

Comment: Same pom.xml file is working on another machine with used same artifactory from both machine

Comment: Have you checked the POM files in your local repository; e.g. your `~/.m2` directory?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong. I keep here because Stephen C made a good comment.

Comment: here I'm not store any artifact in the local repository (~/.m2) folder. This folder is delete after every build.